# Prevent table row select on button click inside <td>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

How to prevent executing javascript code on < tr with class="clientpayer-link" when in last td button is clicked and execute javascript code for that button???

I have table displaying customers in modal form and when I select a customer I close the modal form and pass values to text box. 
Inside the table that is in modal form for each row I have edit button. What I'm trying to do is if I notice that some data from customer is invalid i want to click on Edit button and to show another Modal form (over existing) for Editing Customer records, and the modal with customers still stay open.

The problem is that I have class on tr class="clientpayer-link" and also have script to fetch and pass values to textboxes:

```
 $(document).on('click', "#ClientPayer", function (e) {
            salecreate.loadClientPayer();
            $("#choiceModal").modal('show');
            e.preventDefault();
        });

loadClientPayer: function () {
    var url = "/Sale/GetClientPayer";

    $("#choiceModal .modal-body").html("Loading ...");

    $.post(url,
        function (data) {
            $("#choiceModal .modal-body").html(data);
            salecreate.initTables();
        });
},
```

When I try to click on edit button, tr click event occures and the cutomer list modal is closed, data is passed.
When I try to remove td class, then I can open edit customer modal form.

Here is my html

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover " id="listClientPV">
       <thead>
              <tr>
                  <th class="hideMe">ID</th>
                  <th>Name</th>
                  <th></th>
               </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
              @foreach (var c in Model)
              {
               <tr class="clientpayer-link">
                  <td id="ClientpayerId" class="hideMe">@c.ID</td>
                  <td id="ClientpayerName">@c.CustName</td>
                  <td>
                  <a href="#" id="editCust" title="Edit" role="button" class="modalForms" data-url="@Url.Action("EditCustomers", "Sale", new {ID=c.ID })"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a>
                  </td>
               </tr>
               }
         </tbody>
</table>
```

This is Edit Button code:

```
$(document).on('click', '.modalForms', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var url = $(this).data('url');
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: 'GET'
            }).done(function (response) {
                $('#createEditResult').html(response);
                $('#createEdit').modal('show');
            });
        });
```

Here clientpayer-link event:

```
$(document).on('click', ".clientpayer-link", function (e) {     

$("#SaleService_ClientPayer").val($(this).find("#ClientpayerId").text());
        $("#ClientPayer").val($(this).find("#ClientpayerName").text());

        $("#choiceModal").modal('hide');

        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

Thanks in advance for answering.

Comment: Where is the `tr` click event? You are showing a click event for `#ClientPayer` which is not in your HTML code. I do see the edit button and its click event. You also are creating the same `id` (like `id="ClientpayerId"`) in a loop... `id`'s need to be unique.

Comment: $(document).on('click', ".clientpayer-link", function (e) {

            $("#SaleService_ClientPayer").val($(this).find("#ClientpayerId").text());
            $("#ClientPayer").val($(this).find("#ClientpayerName").text());

            $("#choiceModal").modal('hide');

            e.preventDefault();
        });

Comment: In your edit button click event, under `e.preventDefault();` ... have you tried putting `e.stopPropagation();`? This should stop the click event from bubbling up and triggering other click events.

Comment: @zgood Thank You very much that's it the solution, I put e.stopPropagation(); instead of e.preventDefault(); and now is working. Thank You very much...